# How to add docker label after image is made

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know that there is a LABEL available in Dockerfile.  But I was wondering how to add additional labels to the image after it is built?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 51):

It's indeed not possible to **add** a label to an existing image. Strictly speaking, adding a label would change the images checksum, thus its id, thus it's no longer the same image.

But you can build an image *based* on your existing image with a label added, and then tag this image with the name of the previously existing image.
Technically it adds a layer on top of your existing image and thus just "overrides" previous labels.

It's also possible to do this with a single command. Given you want to add a label to the image "debian:latest", you build *FROM* that image and tag the new image at the same time.

```
echo "FROM debian:latest" | docker build --label my_new_label="arbitrary value" -t "debian:latest" -
```

Proof that "adding" the label worked:

```
$ docker inspect -f "{{json .Config.Labels }}" debian:latest
{"my_new_label":"arbitrary value"}
```

Comment: ⁺¹, but it is worth noting that if the image was completely cached, label won't change.

Comment: @Hi-Angel it will work with cached images. I just tested it, getting the same label changed twice in an already cached image. Also, it makes sense since you are creating a new image based on the old one and retagging it to the same, but it is still a new one.

Answer (score -3):

The idea behind docker is that you have a Dockerfile and it is easy to build again your image, adding a LABEL.

You could hack the image, but it is not worth the work.

Modify (slightly) your Dockerfile, and run again

`docker build -t mytag .`

Comment: Also, worth pointing out https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21721 which describes what the question is looking for but doesn't exist yet. So, the real answer is "no", you have to rebuild the image.

Comment: If you are trying to say that the correct avenue is to add the label to the Dockerfile and then rebuild the entire image, ensuring that the previous build's layers will be reused, your answer doesn't explain that *at all*. In fact, to an person who doesn't know much about Docker, your answer can make it seem that `-t mytag` is how one adds a label, when that's not what it's doing—it's tagging a newly built image.

Answer (score -5):

## Short answer

You can run:
`docker tag <image ID> my_image_name:latest`

## Long answer

Let's suppose you build image using this command:

`docker build .`

However you forgot to specify tag when building it. So When you run `docker images`, you will receive this output:

```
REPOSITORY                                   TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
<none>                                       <none>       ebe162908513   6 minutes ago   92.7MB
```

You can run following command to add a tag to existing image:

`docker tag ebe162908513 my_image_name:latest`

After running `docker images`, you can see your image nicely tagged:

```
REPOSITORY                                   TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
my_image_name                                latest       ebe162908513   6 minutes ago   92.7MB
```

Comment: Tags aren't the same as labels.