# change existing labels of a docker image

Tags: docker

I am trying to modify existing labels of a docker  image,  by running a new *container* with the required label...
(following
https://voltwu.github.io/blog/docker/2020/08/11/manage-labels-on-docker)

...but I realized that labels of the new *image* did not change...
do labels get propagated from docker containers to images?

are there other ways to do it, without re-building from dockerfile?

(I have generated my image by committing changes inside a container, so my docker file does not have those modifications -- https://www.developer.com/design/building-docker-images-from-container/)

thanks

Comment: I would recommend using a Dockerfile for building images. Using commit is an anti-pattern.

Comment: yeah, I was wondering if there is a way in the case when you did most of the work in a container...

Comment: If recreating the image is painful, then that's a sign you should have automated the build, and a Dockerfile is the standard way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Having a post-build step that does introspection on the container and then adds the new label to the image is probably the best way to approach this.

e.g.: [How to add docker label after image is made](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828219)

Comment: well, I guess the answer is no then -- in what you suggested in again re-building the image -- thanks